# Dynamic Drop Down List in Excel - IF statement?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, drop-down-menu

I am looking to create a Dynamic drop down list where if I select a specific line item in the drop down, the adjacent cell will display the value that the line item is associated with.

Ex: If I select Apples, I want the next cell to display the Euros that is associated with that item from a source list. I'm assuming this can be solved by an "If" statement, but not 100% sure.

Comment: Start with the formula (in the adjacent cell): `=IF(A1="Apples","Euros",IF(A1="Bananas","USD",""))`. Just build it up from there.

Comment: How do I do this for an array of answers? There is a table of products with prices associated, and  I want to display a dropdown where depending on the item from the dropdown, the associated price will show in a single cell next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an INDEX:

`=INDEX("The Range where the prices are listed",$D$15)`

With D15 being the output of your Dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `VLOOKUP`.

In column A are all the drop-down values, as defined by the range E2:E5.

In column B is the formula `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$F$5,2,FALSE),"--")`

[image]